# Creating a decision table with accompanied procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rules

I'm trying to think of the best way to write a procedure to evaluate a decision table in SQL Server.

The way I've begun doing it (see VERY simplified example below) would work fine except for the rows where that particular parameter doesn't matter. So, any one claim could fit the scenario in Row 4, provided it's of the type medical.The query, having found a match doesn't even evaluate the other rows. Is there a better way to do this?

I was thinking I could rank the rows of the table from most complicated scenario to least and then select the top row that fits, and that'd probably work, but in future, many more rows will be added to the table and each one would require an analysis of where it would fall in the table. Some situations might even conflict. 
I want the *best* match for the scenario.

I currently have something that does something like this:

```sql
create table TTable(  RowID varchar(max)
                    , ClaimType varchar(max)
                    , Insurance varchar(max)  
                    , Eligibilty varchar(max)
                    , Result varchar(max)  
                    , Assignment varchar(max)    
                    , Admission varchar(max))
Insert into TTable (RowID, ClaimType, Insurance, Eligibility, Result ,Assignment, Admission)
values ('1' , 'Medical' , 'Insured' , 'Eligible' , 'Approval', 'AssignNurse' , 'Admit')
,('2' , 'Medical' , 'Uninsured' , 'N/A' , 'Denial' , 'N/A' ,'N/A')
,('3' , 'Medical' , 'N/A' , 'IncomeEligible' , 'Pend' , 'AssignReviewer' , 'Pend')
,('4' ,' Medical' , 'N/A' , 'N/A' , 'Pend' , 'Pend' , 'Pend')


create procedure getdecision(  @ClaimID uniqueidentifier)

declare @Type
declare @Insurance
declare @Eligibility

Select @Type = Type
From claims
where claimid = @ClaimID

select @Insurance = Insurance
       @Eligibility = Eligibility
from MemberInsurance 
where membemberid = (select memberid from claims where claimid = @claimid)

select RowID, 
        Result,
        Assignment,
        Admission
From ttable t
WHERE @Type = ClaimType
and Case when t.Insurance = 'N/A' 
    then @Type
    Else t.ClaimType
    End
and Case when t.Eligible = 'N/A' 
    then @Eligibility
    else t.Eligibilty
    end
```

Comment: What defines the "best match"? Is it different for each parameter? Should the procedure always return a single row?

Comment: Yes, each claim should only evaluate to one row. It's basically if a claim has these properties (colums 2, 3, 4) perform these actions (5, 6, 7). My real world situation has many, many more properties columns and quite a few more actions columns.

Comment: The description of what you want is way too vague.  Maybe give some sample data (from all the tables involved) and desired results.   Right now it is unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I think that unless you can specify a very long "if>then" series of logic here that will encompass all results, you're going to end up with a "random" row at some point. You could incorporate some sort of arbitrary "weight" value into an order by maybe? As @TabAlleman said, it's still unclear what the results should be. Or perhaps you need to handle the "is null" logic in your initial statements, rather than at the ending case statements. That would give you better control over the logic for the missing values.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with the consensus here. There's not enough detail in the question to provide a meaningful answer. For some good advice and tools to help, I recommend reading over [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). There's stuff in there that I use just about every day.

Comment: I am not sure how many case statements you are willing to write if this is just a sample of what your actual data looks like. If you want to rank all rows, you would want to create another column and write case statements for all the columns that your "rank" is based on. To make it easier I would create a table with columns that correspond to values in the current table and rank them based on your criteria. You can then select whichever row has the highest rank and this also allows for scalability for future as well.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I didn't explain this very well. The theory with the decision table is that instead of evaluating a bunch of rules individually, put the conditions in a table and then when the claim is saved, the procedure gets the relevant parameters for that claim from the database and then compares those parameters to the ones in the table (columns 2, 3, 4) of possible scenarios and spits back out the actions (columns 5, 6, 7).

Comment: So, scenario 1: someone makes a medical claim, they have insurance, they are eligible. So, the claim is approved, a nurse is assigned and they are admitted to the clinic.
Scenario 2, the claim is medical, they are uninsured, it doesn't matter if they're eligible because there's no insurance to be eligible with, so the claim is denied, no nurse assigned, no admission.

Comment: Scenario 3, Its a medical claim, and then it doesn't matter if they have insurance because they are income eligible for admission to the hospital, so we pend the decision on admission and assign someone to review the situation. The decision to admit is pended as well.

Comment: Scenario 4, this is where the problem comes in. It's a medical claim, but no other information has been entered on the claim, so the decision on all three actions is to pend. Unfortunately, when I run this on test cases, all of them evaluate to row 4, because it fits any of those scenarios.